# Typo equivalent for a speech recognition mistake

Tags: single-word-requests

A typographical error (a.k.a. typo) is a mistake made in the typing process (typing "hlelo" instead of "hello").

Is there any word to designate a mistake made when writing a text through a speech recognition program?

The error may result from the imperfectness of the speech recognition engine,  from the imperfectness of the speaker's pronunciation, or from a mixture of both.

I am aware of the question [“Typo” for speech?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/282847/17712) but it focuses on the imperfectness of the speaker's pronunciation, and doesn't consider speech recognition.

Comment: I’ve just seen *speech recognition error*.  No abbreviation.

Comment: Yeah, you also get "OCR errors", and that's the only term I've seen used for them.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks, I guess in the case of speech recognition, we'd say ASR error then (ASR = automatic speech recognition).

Comment: Or "glitch" maybe?

Comment: "Transcription error," or the word was "mistranscribed," maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you're looking for, as I understand you want a word that implies that the speech recognition engine made a mistake, but the slang word *speako* might get the message across.

From [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speako):

> Noun
>
> speako ‎(plural speakos)
>
> A mistake made when speaking, for example saying the wrong word accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

I propose "dicto" for "dictographical error."  Dictographical isn't a word, but dictograph definitely is.

"Dicto" can be retroactively applied to errors in dictation processes, even if a human was involved in transcribing the dictation.