# Is there a term for unconsciously using a wrong word when speaking because you were otherwise looking at, listening to, or thinking about that word?

Tags: single-word-requests

As a contrived example, you might be looking at the book "1984" when someone ask you when you were born, so you answer "1984" by mistake.  You do, of course, know when you were born.  You just had a little neurolinguistic slip.  So, is there a word that perfectly describes that situation — or perhaps the word?  It is not a "malapropism" or any such failure to *know* what is correct; it is just an ephemeral "slip" of the brain.

Comment: It's a cognitive phenomenon, but I don't think there's a specific term for it (I would be happy to be wrong about that)--I think "neurolinguistic slip" is as close as you're going to get. The underlying neurophysical mechanism is probably similar to that of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect

Comment: This seems to be the most relevant and useful information yet.  If my question begs neologism, I would propose "Stroop slip" for public consumption. :)

Comment: @GiHe - Consider asking your question at [Psychology.SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/). There might be someone there who can help you..

Comment: It sounds a little like an OCD symptom...maybe you need to restrict the Q.

Comment: Yes, a slip of the tongue, aka lapsus linguae. Freud describes this phenomenon. One of the ways the unconscious manifests itself....

Comment: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/articles/201203/slips-the-tongue "Freud's ideas, especially about the ubiquity of sexual urges, have been dethroned" ... " A language-production system that is error-prone allows for the "novel production" of words. It is prima facie evidence of linguistic flexibility, proof of the great dexterity of the human mind."

Comment: I use *think-o* (like typo, but *neuro* would probably be a better analog), or more crudely, *brain fart*.

Answer (score 2):

In psycholinguistics, this is a type of **priming**, defined in [Insights from Psycholinguistics](https://benjamins.com/catalog/lllt.30) as "the phenomenon in which prior exposure to specific language forms or meanings influences a speaker’s subsequent language comprehension or production."

We're often primed by semantically related words rather than the word itself. Like if you saw the words "collar," "leash," and "walk," and someone asked you to name an animal, you'd probably be more likely to say "dog" than "cat." But that might also happen if you were just looking at the word "dog," too - it's just a more direct form of priming.

So in linguistic terms, the phenomenon you're describing is a **speech error conditioned by priming**.

Comment: Hello, Aralcar. Is the term 'priming' actually used for other than external influences? Your answer certainly fits for ' ...  because you were otherwise looking at, listening to ... that word'.

Comment: Hi, Edwin. The term 'priming' comes from the broader field of [psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)), where the effect can come from any stimulus - anything that elicits a response. What did you have in mind with 'other than external influences'?

Comment: When one's mind was on other things, not (present, first-hand) outside influences. Thinking about music and answering "1812".

Comment: I see - thanks for clarifying. In psychology (as in physiology) stimuli can be internal or external, so in theory psycholinguistic stimuli could also be internal or external. But you're right - psycholinguists don't really talk or write about priming from purely internal stimuli (as far as I know), maybe because it's difficult to test for it empirically.

So if someone were independently thinking about a word or concept without having been influenced by any external stimulus, and they became more likely to produce that word or a related word, that effect might not be called priming.

Answer (score -1):

This would most generally be called a ***slip of the tongue***. These are sometimes called ***Freudian slips***, but that really describes a specific circumstance in which the words you say belie some unconscious thought or desire. You'll often hear the term used without its proper psychoanalytical context to describe any slip of the tongue, though.

Comment: I would say that it is a specific kind of "slip of the tongue" but is not typically a "Freudian slip" (which is a different specific kind of "slip of the tongue").  I am looking for a word that is *exactly* correct (in the mathematical sense of "exact"), which "slip of the tongue" is not because other slips of the tongue are not this kind.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @GiHe The discussion at https://www.healthline.com/health/freudian-slip is actually quite similar, perhaps a superset rather than equivalent or isomorphic. Note the examples: "a child who accidentally calls their teacher “Mom” is simply transitioning from spending most of day with their mother to spending most of the day with their teacher. A stressed parent who calls one child by the name of another child (or the family dog) is often simply busy and tired."

Comment: That would be (and was) the answer to [typo for speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282847/typo-for-speech/286342#286342). 'Slip of the tongue' is too ballpark (and Freudian slip, as you say, inappropriate).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The accepted answer there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_error which is a wide umbrella phrase that certainly includes the OP's phenomenon, as well as Freudian slips (which the article notes is a "somewhat-outdated" psycholinguistic explanation).

Comment: I'm saying that if 'slip of the tongue' (or 'speech error') were a fair answer here, this question should be CV-d as a duplicate rather than answered. It's the 'because you were otherwise looking at, listening to, or thinking about that word' caveat that licenses this question and proscribes ballpark answers. _[I]s there a word that **perfectly** describes that situation ..._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't say that it's "a fair answer" ... it's obviously too broad. I simply pointed out that the very broad term "speech error" was the accepted answer to that *different* question, and not the other terms mentioned here (both of which, like the OP's phenomenon, are subsets of "speech error").

Comment: @EdwinAshworth P.S. It's good practice to @ someone you respond to so they are alerted that you responded.

Comment: slip of the tongue aka lapsus linguae. Same as Freudian slip.

Comment: @Lambie, "slip of the tongue" is too broad; it is a superset that includes both (1) what I am calling the "Stroop slip" for now and (2) the Freudian slip.  Also, the Freudian slip and the "Stroop slip" are non-overlapping, neurolinguistically.  The "Stroop slip" feels like an artifact of incomplete task-switching from one conscious context to another.  The Freudian slip is an involuntary revelation of an unconscious thought.

Comment: @Jim Balter Is there a word for being corrected for an error you commit say one time in a thousand?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Look at it from my perspective: I almost didn't see your response in our one and only exchange to date because I wasn't tagged. I didn't know your practice and hadn't noticed your 61k rep. I did not intend my comment as criticism, certainly not for a rare *slip*; sorry if it came across that way. (BTW, I appreciate your clever phrasing. "omission" applies broadly.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm still doing a bit of research, but here's what I've come up with for now -

***Echolalia***

> Echolalia is the unsolicited repetition of vocalizations made by
> another person (when repeated by the same person, it is called
> palilalia). In its profound form it is automatic and effortless. It is
> one of the echophenomena, closely related to echopraxia, the automatic
> repetition of movements made by another person; both are "subsets of
> imitative behavior" whereby sounds or actions are imitated "without
> explicit awareness". Echolalia may be an immediate reaction to a
> stimulus or may be delayed.

Source - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echolalia)

---

> Echolalia: The involuntary parrotlike repetition (echoing) of a word
> or phrase just spoken by another person.

Source - [medicinenet.com](https://www.medicinenet.com/echolalia/definition.htm)

---

There's also [***mirroring***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirroring_%28psychology%29) -

> Mirroring is the behaviour in which one person subconsciously imitates
> the gesture, speech pattern, or attitude of another.

However, this doesn't really suit the purpose of this question very well...

From Wikipedia -

> Mirroring generally takes place unconsciously as individuals react
> with the situation. Mirroring is common in conversation, as the
> listeners will typically smile or frown along with the speaker, as
> well as imitate body posture or attitude about the topic. Individuals
> may be more willing to empathize with and accept people whom they
> believe hold similar interests and beliefs, and thus mirroring the
> person with whom one is speaking may establish connections between the
> individuals involved.

Comment: "Echolalia" is very interesting and superficially similar, but seems (1) pathological (i.e.,  "indicative of an underlying disorder") and (2) bound to *external* stimuli (and thus not applicable to the case where a word leaks from your thoughts to your speech).  There may not be a perfect word (*mot juste*) for this particular kind of slip of the tongue...

Comment: @GiHe Justin's answer references "palilalia", which deals with (2), but I think (1) is an overwhelming objection--this is obsessive pathological echoing, which is very different from a "Stroop slip".

Comment: I first saw that word in _Slaughterhouse-five_...not sure it applies here.

Comment: @Cascabel - I can't seem to find a specific word or phrase tailored to fit OP's question.. Nevertheless, I'm just gonna leave *echolalia* here.. and go read/watch *Slaughterhouse-five*...

Comment: _Caracoles_...this is a must-read book for people trying to understand WWII as written  on a personal level.

Comment: Also see _King Rat_ by Clavell,...then read _Gravity's Rainbow_, by Thomas Pynchon...

Comment: echolalia is not right here

Comment: @Cascabel - I will make this my priority :)